# JsonProperty(PropertyName) não reconhece e não atribui valores para o objeto

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-web-api, newtonsoft

Estou criando uma `API`, método tipo POST, onde o `payload` é composto por 3 classes com a seguinte estrutura:

```
//Classe principal do payload
public class Representante
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "representatives")]
    public List<Representante> Representantes { get; set; }
}

//Classe que compõe o tipo da lista acima
[JsonObject(Title = "Representative")]
public class Representante
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "personCode")]
    public string CodigoPessoa { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "cpf")]
    public string Cpf { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "clientPart")]
    public ClienteParte ClienteParte { get; set; }
 }

//Classe referente ao objeto que compõe a classe 'Representante'
[JsonObject(Title = "clientPart")]
public class ClienteParte
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "numberDocument")]
    public string NumeroDocumento { get; set; }
}
```

Ao realizar um teste para validar se tudo que informei no `payload` abaixo reflete nos objetos de entrada, notei que o objeto `ClienteParte ("clientPart")` é retornado com valor nulos. Preciso informar uma estrutura diferente no PropertyName para entender que a  propriedade pertence a uma classe dentro de outra `classe?` Exemplo: `[JsonProperty(PropertyName="clientPart.name")]`

Payload:

```
{
"sellerCode":332,
"representatives": [ {
          "personCode": 41333440,
          "cpf": 67788947687,
          "name": "TAPIXU ENMU FIHJAE",
          "signatureType": "C",
          "clientPart": [{
               "name":" JOAO DA SILVA",
               "numberDocument ":"67826789372"
          }],
}]
}
```

Retorno refletido na classe de entrada:

> [image: Printscreen retorno API]

Comment: Acho que você só se confundiu um pouco, olha o json, o clientpart tá entre colchetes, ou seja, é uma lista, na sua classe Representante ele está apenas um objeto

Comment: `clientPart` está mal formado, tem uma virgula sobrando e a chave `numberDocument ` tem um espaço dentro entre o `t` e a `"`.

Comment: O erro estava no colchetes mesmo. Corrigi aqui e funcionou. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

O `ClientPart` é um `array` (uma lista), então por isso o seu modelo tipo está errado, deve ser como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public class Representante
{
    [JsonPropertyName("sellerCode")]
    public int SellerCode { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("representatives")]
    public Representative[] Representatives { get; set; }
}

public class Representative
{
    [JsonPropertyName("personCode")]
    public int PersonCode { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("cpf")]
    public long CPF { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("signatureType")]
    public string SignatureType { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("clientPart")]
    public Clientpart[] ClientPart { get; set; }
}

public class Clientpart
{
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("numberDocument")]
    public string NumberDocument { get; set; }
}
```